# What's wrong with this colored JTree? (custom renderer problem)

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I want write custom TreeCellRenderer to have Root, nodes and leafs in different color.

This is my code:

```
tree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        {

            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;

            if (node.isRoot()) {
                super.setBackground(Color.red);
            } else if (node.getChildCount() > 0) {
                super.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            } else if (leaf) {
                super.setBackground(Color.green);
            }
            return super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

        }

    }
});
```

Unfortunately only selected node changes color.

What am I doing wrong? TIA for help.

//update:
I correlated my code, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you mean `setBackgroundColor()` and not `setBackgroundSelectionColor()`, which, as its name suggests, only sets the color for the selected state.

Your use of `super` is **super**fluous [credit for this witty remark goes to [Carl Smotricz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25829/carl-smotricz)].

Comment: Oops... I must drink more cofee and use notepad instead NetBeans. Thank You.

Comment: OK it's setBackgroundNonSelectionColor().

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call super.getTreeCellRendererComponent **before** you set the colors (and eventually return this) ? Try setting colors first and returning what super.getTreeCellRendererComponent returns